# How to move footer automatically downward when new content add into the body?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Hello everyone I have created a navigation bar and footer in different pages and then add into ever page through include PHP function. my issue  when I add content a lot into the body then the body content overlap the footer. Currently I am using bootstrap 5 for this website

**this is the code of footer**

```
  <!-- Footer -->
<footer class="text-center text-lg-start bg-info text-muted">
    <!-- Section: Social media -->
    <section class="d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-lg-between p-4 border-bottom">

    </section>
    <!-- Section: Social media -->

    <!-- Section: Links  -->
    <section class="">
        <div class="container text-center text-md-start mt-5">
            <!-- Grid row -->
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <!-- Grid column -->
                <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mx-auto mb-4">
                    <!-- Content -->
                    <h6 class="text-uppercase fw-bold mb-4">
                        <i class="fas fa-gem me-3"></i>Company name
                    </h6>
                    <p>
                        Here you can use rows and columns to organize your footer content. Lorem ipsum
                        dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <!-- Grid column -->

                <!-- Grid column -->
                <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 mx-auto mb-4">
                    <!-- Links -->
                    <h6 class="text-uppercase fw-bold mb-4">
                        Products
                    </h6>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Angular</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#!" class="text-reset">React</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Vue</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Laravel</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <!-- Grid column -->

                <!-- Grid column -->
                <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 mx-auto mb-4">
                    <!-- Links -->
                    <h6 class="text-uppercase fw-bold mb-4">
                        Useful links
                    </h6>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Pricing</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Settings</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Orders</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Help</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <!-- Grid column -->

                <!-- Grid column -->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mx-auto mb-md-0 mb-4">
                    <!-- Links -->
                    <h6 class="text-uppercase fw-bold mb-4">Contact</h6>
                    <p><i class="fas fa-home me-3"></i> New York, NY 10012, US</p>
                    <p>
                        <i class="fas fa-envelope me-3"></i>
                        info@example.com
                    </p>
                    <p><i class="fas fa-phone me-3"></i> + 01 234 567 88</p>
                    <p><i class="fas fa-print me-3"></i> + 01 234 567 89</p>
                </div>
                <!-- Grid column -->
            </div>
            <!-- Grid row -->
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Section: Links  -->

    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="text-center p-4" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);">
        © 2021 Copyright:
        <a class="text-reset fw-bold" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/">MDBootstrap.com</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->
</footer>
<!-- Footer -->
```

**this is the code of navigation bar**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SMS</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="bootstrapfile/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="bootstrapfile/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-info navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SMS</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"  data-bs-toggle = "collapse" data-bs-target="#mango">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"  id="mango">
            <ul class="navbar-nav" id="mango">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Home</a>
                </li>
    
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">About us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">About us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Login Panel</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="studentLogin.php">Student Login</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Teacher Login</a></li>
            </ul>
    
    
    
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    
    
    <br>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

**this is the code of registeration page
where i add navigation bar and footer with include function**

```
<?php
include "navigation.php"
?>

    <body>
    <section class="vh-100" >
        <div class="container h-100">
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-11">
                    <div class="card text-black" style="border-radius: 50px;">
                        <div class="card-body p-md-5">
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-5 order-2 order-lg-1">
    
                                    <p class="text-center h1 fw-bold mb-5 mx-1 mx-md-4 mt-4">Sign up</p>
    
                                    <form class="mx-1 mx-md-4">
    
                                        <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                            <i class="fas fa-user fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                            <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                                <input type="text" id="form3Example1c" class="form-control" />
                                                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1c">Your Name</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
    
                                        <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                            <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                            <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                                <input type="email" id="form3Example3c" class="form-control" />
                                                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example3c">Your Email</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
    
                                        <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                            <i class="fas fa-lock fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                            <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                                <input type="password" id="form3Example4c" class="form-control" />
                                                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4c">Password</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
    
                                        <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                            <i class="fas fa-key fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                            <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                                <input type="password" id="form3Example4cd" class="form-control" />
                                                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4cd">Repeat your password</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
    
    
                                        <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                            <i class="fas fa-key fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                            <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                                <input type="password" id="form3Example4cd" class="form-control" />
                                                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4cd">Date of Birth</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
    
                                        <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                            <i class="fas fa-key fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                            <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                                <input type="password" id="form3Example4cd" class="form-control" />
                                                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4cd">Date of Join</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
    
    
                                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mx-4 mb-3 mb-lg-4">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Register</button>
                                        </div>
    
    
                                        <div class="form-check d-flex justify-content-center mb-5">
    
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="form2Example3">
                                                <a style="text-decoration: none" class="text-danger" href="studentLogin.php">Back to Login Page</a>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
    
                                    </form>
    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-7 d-flex align-items-center order-1 order-lg-2">
    
                                    <img src="draw1.webp" class="img-fluid" alt="Sample image">
    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    
    <?php include "footer.php" ?>
    </body>
```

**this is the image**
[enter image description here][2]

Comment: Please share html and css with proper code

Comment: don't just code dump your project. Create a reproducible minimal example so we can help. From what im seeing right now you are working with either hardcoded height for content, or position absolute on your register block. Remove either of those and it will go into place.

Comment: i dont know why you mark neagtive on my question i add everything in this question all the code there is not linked css i used bootstrap 5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The code of "footer" where is? I see only the SAME code of navbar

Comment: i am sorry i am changing it now

Comment: Your navigation bar code ends with `</body></html>`, and after that, you have a `<body>` again ...? Maybe you should learn the proper structure of an HTML document, _before_ you try to dynamically assemble one.

Comment: `<section class="vh-100" >` - that `vh-100` class means, that element can grow to 100% of the viewport size - but not above it. If you have more content in this section than fits into this height you specified, then the rest of the content will _overflow_ this section. Maybe you want to use the `min-vh-100` class instead - that applies a _minimum_ height of 100vh, instead of a _fixed_ one.

Comment: @Cbore thanks for this answer everybody is critcizing how i code but you answer very well

Answer (score 0):

Let's see, there are some errors in your `navigation.php` code, because you are opening the `<html>` and `<body>` tag. And right after, in `registation.php` you are calling `navigation.php` and you are opening another `<body>` tag. That is, you are joining 2 HTML documents. Instead of `<br>` you can use `mb-2` or another "mb-" class from Bootstrap, because it means `margin-button` and leaves a dividing space between another element.

Also, inside `footer.php` place your scripts (remember that you are one line before the `<body>` so just place them at the end of the footer tag.

Registration page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>SMS</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link href="bootstrapfile/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php
         include "navigation.php"
         ?>
      <section>
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
               <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-11">
                  <div class="card text-black" style="border-radius: 50px;">
                     <div class="card-body p-md-5">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                           <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-5 order-2 order-lg-1">
                              <p class="text-center h1 fw-bold mb-5 mx-1 mx-md-4 mt-4">Sign up</p>
                              <form class="mx-1 mx-md-4">
                                 <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                    <i class="fas fa-user fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                    <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                       <input type="text" id="form3Example1c" class="form-control" />
                                       <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1c">Your Name</label>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                    <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                    <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                       <input type="email" id="form3Example3c" class="form-control" />
                                       <label class="form-label" for="form3Example3c">Your Email</label>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                    <i class="fas fa-lock fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                    <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                       <input type="password" id="form3Example4c" class="form-control" />
                                       <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4c">Password</label>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                    <i class="fas fa-key fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                    <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                       <input type="password" id="form3Example4cd" class="form-control" />
                                       <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4cd">Repeat your password</label>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                    <i class="fas fa-key fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                    <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                       <input type="password" id="form3Example4cd" class="form-control" />
                                       <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4cd">Date of Birth</label>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                    <i class="fas fa-key fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                    <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                       <input type="password" id="form3Example4cd" class="form-control" />
                                       <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4cd">Date of Join</label>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mx-4 mb-3 mb-lg-4">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Register</button>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="form-check d-flex justify-content-center mb-5">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="form2Example3">
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none" class="text-danger" href="studentLogin.php">Back to Login Page</a>
                                    </label>
                                 </div>
                              </form>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-7 d-flex align-items-center order-1 order-lg-2">
                              <img src="draw1.webp" class="img-fluid" alt="Sample image">
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
      <?php include "footer.php" ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Navigation.php:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-info navbar-light mb-2">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SMS</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#mango">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mango">
    <ul class="navbar-nav" id="mango">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Home</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">About us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">About us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Login Panel</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="studentLogin.php">Student Login</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Teacher Login</a></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Footer.php:

```
<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="text-center text-lg-start bg-info text-muted">
   <!-- Section: Social media -->
   <section class="d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-lg-between p-4 border-bottom">
   </section>
   <!-- Section: Social media -->
   <!-- Section: Links  -->
   <section class="">
      <div class="container text-center text-md-start mt-5">
         <!-- Grid row -->
         <div class="row mt-3">
            <!-- Grid column -->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mx-auto mb-4">
               <!-- Content -->
               <h6 class="text-uppercase fw-bold mb-4">
                  <i class="fas fa-gem me-3"></i>Company name
               </h6>
               <p>
                  Here you can use rows and columns to organize your footer content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
               </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Grid column -->
            <!-- Grid column -->
            <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 mx-auto mb-4">
               <!-- Links -->
               <h6 class="text-uppercase fw-bold mb-4">
                  Products
               </h6>
               <p>
                  <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Angular</a>
               </p>
               <p>
                  <a href="#!" class="text-reset">React</a>
               </p>
               <p>
                  <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Vue</a>
               </p>
               <p>
                  <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Laravel</a>
               </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Grid column -->
            <!-- Grid column -->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 mx-auto mb-4">
               <!-- Links -->
               <h6 class="text-uppercase fw-bold mb-4">
                  Useful links
               </h6>
               <p>
                  <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Pricing</a>
               </p>
               <p>
                  <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Settings</a>
               </p>
               <p>
                  <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Orders</a>
               </p>
               <p>
                  <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Help</a>
               </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Grid column -->
            <!-- Grid column -->
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mx-auto mb-md-0 mb-4">
               <!-- Links -->
               <h6 class="text-uppercase fw-bold mb-4">Contact</h6>
               <p><i class="fas fa-home me-3"></i> New York, NY 10012, US</p>
               <p>
                  <i class="fas fa-envelope me-3"></i> info@example.com
               </p>
               <p><i class="fas fa-phone me-3"></i> + 01 234 567 88</p>
               <p><i class="fas fa-print me-3"></i> + 01 234 567 89</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Grid column -->
         </div>
         <!-- Grid row -->
      </div>
   </section>
   <!-- Section: Links  -->
   <!-- Copyright -->
   <div class="text-center p-4" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);">
      © 2021 Copyright:
      <a class="text-reset fw-bold" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/">MDBootstrap.com</a>
   </div>
   <!-- Copyright -->
</footer>
<!-- Footer -->
<!-- HERE PASTE YOUR JAVASCRIPT TAGS, REMEMBER THATS THE END OF THE BODY TAG -->
<script src="bootstrapfile/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're working on a project so it will be important to setup Partials.
Partials pages are default pages we setup so that whenever we render a new page first the code goes through partial before execution. The best practices are setup a 'Layout page'and a 'Partials page'.